# input in python raised" ValueError: I/O operation on closed file."

Tags: python, sockets, input

I have a server in python which takes a char or string from the user, and the input method keep raising a ValueError that only should accure while using files. and the problem is not to print somthing to the console, because the print above it work

```
    while True:  # encrypt from now
        show = """\n
                'a' = ask server to authorize this user
                'm' = write a message
                'e' = close connection (exit)
                'c' = see who's connected and who you can talk to
                """
        print(show)
        try:
            act = input(pending_c + "\t\t\tact:")[0]
```

```
type hereTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\itama\PycharmProjects\cyberProj\proj_code\newClient.py", line 217, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\itama\PycharmProjects\cyberProj\proj_code\newClient.py", line 213, in main
    start_sending(s)
  File "C:\Users\itama\PycharmProjects\cyberProj\proj_code\newClient.py", line 207, in start_sending
    start_sending(s1, True)
  File "C:\Users\itama\PycharmProjects\cyberProj\proj_code\newClient.py", line 200, in start_sending
    start_comm(s)
  File "C:\Users\itama\PycharmProjects\cyberProj\proj_code\newClient.py", line 113, in start_comm
    act = input()[0]
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

```
def start_comm(s):
while True:  # encrypt from now
    show = """\n
            'a' = ask server to authorize this user
            'm' = write a message
            'e' = close connection (exit)
            'c' = see who's connected and who you can talk to
            """
    print(show)
    try:
        act = input(pending_c + "\t\t\tact:")[0]
    except IndexError:
        print("try again...")
        continue
    except ValueError:
        import sys
        print(pending_c + "\t\t\tact:")
        sys.stdin.readline()[0]
    if act in ['a', 'm', 'e', 'c']:
```

Comment: A [mcve] would help. As is, your code doesn't even compile. The `if` is incomplete. What is `s` and why is it never used? What is `pending_c`? When I remove all the undefined stuff, your code kind of "works" for me, it keeps printing and getting input. So the problem must be in another part of your code that you are not showing. Waste of time. Please see [ask].

Comment: s is a socket. and the if is fine, its a 200 line of code and i gave only the part that was relevent... pending_c is a way to change the color of the line using the module colorama. the problem must be in the input because when i tried to keep running the code and replaced the input with a constant value (like 'a' or 'e') the code jumped again in the next input()

Comment: Make a [mcve].  If we can't reproduce the problem you won't get a solution.  It seems like you've overwritten the `input` built-in function.

Comment: I seached my code to see if I overwritten it. I didn't find evidence of that. is it possible the problem is in another line and it for some reason appear there?

Comment: Dude, how often do we need to ask for a [mcve]?

Comment: to reproduce the problem you need to run a server, a backup server, and then connect the client. then login the client, in this stage, the client and the server talks and the input is working. then shut down manually the server. the backup server start recving clients and the client automatically connect to the backup. then when the client and backup start to talk the input stop working. in order reproduce the problem you will need 6 files of code and going to all of this procces or the problem will not accure

Comment: in order to completely overall that input was overwritten I import builtin.input one line before the input, the problem still acurred

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that the problem is in the Python backend code.
input is using sys.stdin to get input, and for some reason. in my code sys.stdim got closed, therefore all trying to input will raise this problem.
in order to solve it you need to reopen the sts.stdin I suggest doing this:

```
    try:
        act = input(pending_c + "\t\t\tact:")[0]
    except ValueError:
        sys.stdin = open(0, 'r')
        act = input(pending_c + "\t\t\tact:")[0]
```

dont forget to import sys to your project